# Javascript dependancy management for single page application

Tags: javascript

I have 100 modules in my library.
I have 5 different websites.
now any website can use any number of modules.
I want just one javascript per website.

----------   Here is what I do --------

Let suppose, 1st website has 2 modules, now these two modules may have dependency on other modules. So let suppose after manual dependency resolution, it turns out that I need total 11 modules for 1st website. So I combine JavaScript files for these 11 modules and minify it.

I do not want any solution which load these JavaScript files asynchronously from server. I want some java/python etc Utility which scan for all modules and resolve dependency and combine and minify into single file.

Question -

How many solutions do provide such functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Require JS](http://requirejs.org/) might load asynchronously in the standard setup but it also has an optimizer that minifies modules and puts them all together in one file